# CSS not showing up in php though file_existis returns true

Tags: php, css

For some reason my css is not showing up.

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="public/css/style.css">
```

**Question**
So what would cause the CSS to show up blank?

**Settings**
I am using Arch Linux and have set up a LAMP with vhosts. My vhost file DocumentRoot is set to /home/codeamend/Projects/www/quick-mvc/ and that is where my tree was printed from.
All my permissions are set properly and have owner 775 of with codeamend:http

**useful output**
I also ran this right above the link tag

```
    <?php echo (file_exists('public/css/style.css') ? "true" : "false"; ?>
```

This returns **true.**

```
  echo __DIR__;
```

/home/codeamend/Projects/www/quick-mvc/views/layouts/default

```
  echo "Request scheme: " . $_SERVER['REQUEST_SCHEME'];
```

http

```
  echo "Request host: " . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
```

quick-mvc

**My layout**

```
http://quick-mvc/
    ├── controllers
    │   ├── front.php
    │   └── rear.php
    │
    ├── index.php <------- home file
    │
    ├── libs
    │   ├── Bootstrap.php
    │   ├── Controller.php
    │   └── View.php
    ├── public
    │   ├── css
    │   │   └── style.css
    │   └── js
    │       └── script.js
    └── views
        ├── front
        │   └── index.php
        ├── layouts
        │   └── default
        │       ├── footer.php
        │       └── header.php
        └── rear
            └── index.php
```

Comment: It's not because php can determine a file exists on the server that it is accessible to the public. Are the sub folders accessible over the webserver? Did you try the full url? If it's linux, are the permissions correct on the folders and css file?

Comment: You're using paths from your project root instead of from the webserver's document root, which I would expect to be pointed at your `public` directory. If that's the case then your css URI should be `/css/style.css` only.

Comment: Try viewing the page source and right-click on the generated URI to the CSS file. Open it in a new window and inspect the URI if something is incorrect.

Comment: I did get this in the console: Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "'http://'quick-mvc/public/css/style.css" (no quotes around http://)

Comment: Santy: yes I did try full path and yes permissions are good.

Comment: Jon Striling my webserver doc root is the same as project root.

Answer (score 0):

Hahaha, Its Happen many times with me... :P (Not laughing on you)

Always Use type and rel in link tag, with css

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="public/css/style.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your structure, try this one

```
<?php echo file_exists(__DIR__.'/public/css/style.css') ? $_SERVER['REQUEST_SCHEME'] . '://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . "/public/css/style.css" : ""; ?>
```

if still does not work, try looking for .htaccess file for the right permissions (if server is Apache)

Comment: I updated my post with info from ideas I got from your post.